# Running into errors compiling C script using zlib.h

Tags: c, zlib

I am currently experiencing issues while attempting to execute my encryptor/decryptor C script. This script was originally developed around a year ago. However, due to a computer reset, I lost several libraries and header files. One specific issue was the absence of the "zlib.h" file, which I managed to fix (maybe).

Now, as I attempt to compile the script using the following command:
`$ gcc main.c -lz -I"C:\msys64\mingw64\include" -w`

Error Log:

```
$ gcc main.c -lz -I"C:\msys64\mingw64\include" -w
In file included from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/_cygwin.h:14,
                 from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/_mingw.h:15,
                 from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/corecrt.h:10,
                 from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/corecrt_stdio_config.h:10,
                 from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:9,
                 from main.c:1:
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stddef.h:18:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘extern’
   18 |   _CRTIMP extern int *__cdecl _errno(void);
      |          ^~~~~~~
      |          ;
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stddef.h:20:19: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_set_errno’
   20 |   errno_t __cdecl _set_errno(int _Value);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stddef.h:21:19: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_get_errno’
   21 |   errno_t __cdecl _get_errno(int *_Value);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stddef.h:24:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘extern’
   24 |   _CRTIMP extern unsigned long __cdecl __threadid(void);
      |          ^~~~~~~
      |          ;
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stddef.h:26:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘extern’
   26 |   _CRTIMP extern uintptr_t __cdecl __threadhandle(void);
      |          ^~~~~~~
      |          ;
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stddef.h:26:36: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘__threadhandle’
   26 |   _CRTIMP extern uintptr_t __cdecl __threadhandle(void);
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/corecrt_stdio_config.h:10,
                 from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:9,
                 from main.c:1:
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/corecrt.h:113:13: error: ‘errno_t’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
  113 | typedef int errno_t;
      |             ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/_cygwin.h:14,
                 from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/_mingw.h:15,
                 from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/corecrt.h:10,
                 from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/corecrt_stdio_config.h:10,
                 from C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:9,
                 from main.c:1:
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stddef.h:21:3: note: previous declaration of ‘errno_t’ with type ‘int’
   21 |   errno_t __cdecl _get_errno(int *_Value);
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from main.c:1:
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1349:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘fgetwc’
 1349 |   wint_t __cdecl fgetwc(FILE *_File);
      |                  ^~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1350:26: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_fgetwchar’
 1350 |   _CRTIMP wint_t __cdecl _fgetwchar(void);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1351:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘fputwc’
 1351 |   wint_t __cdecl fputwc(wchar_t _Ch,FILE *_File);
      |                  ^~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1352:26: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_fputwchar’
 1352 |   _CRTIMP wint_t __cdecl _fputwchar(wchar_t _Ch);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1353:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘getwc’
 1353 |   wint_t __cdecl getwc(FILE *_File);
      |                  ^~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1354:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘getwchar’
 1354 |   wint_t __cdecl getwchar(void);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1355:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘putwc’
 1355 |   wint_t __cdecl putwc(wchar_t _Ch,FILE *_File);
      |                  ^~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1356:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘putwchar’
 1356 |   wint_t __cdecl putwchar(wchar_t _Ch);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1357:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘ungetwc’
 1357 |   wint_t __cdecl ungetwc(wint_t _Ch,FILE *_File);
      |                  ^~~~~~~
In file included from main.c:1:
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/stdio.h:1607:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_wspawnl’
 1607 |   _CRTIMP intptr_t __cdecl _wspawnl(int _Mode,const wchar_t *_Filename,const wchar_t *_ArgList,...);


....




C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:105:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_wexecve’
  105 |   _CRTIMP intptr_t __cdecl _wexecve(const wchar_t *_Filename,const wchar_t *const *_ArgList,const wchar_t *const *_Env);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:106:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_wexecvp’
  106 |   _CRTIMP intptr_t __cdecl _wexecvp(const wchar_t *_Filename,const wchar_t *const *_ArgList);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:107:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_wexecvpe’
  107 |   _CRTIMP intptr_t __cdecl _wexecvpe(const wchar_t *_Filename,const wchar_t *const *_ArgList,const wchar_t *const *_Env);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:129:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘_loaddll’
  129 |   intptr_t __cdecl _loaddll(char *_Filename);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:130:26: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘intptr_t’
  130 |   int __cdecl _unloaddll(intptr_t _Handle);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:131:41: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘intptr_t’
  131 |   int (__cdecl *__cdecl _getdllprocaddr(intptr_t _Handle,char *_ProcedureName,intptr_t _Ordinal))(void);
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:131:79: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘intptr_t’
  131 |   int (__cdecl *__cdecl _getdllprocaddr(intptr_t _Handle,char *_ProcedureName,intptr_t _Ordinal))(void);
      |                                                                               ^~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:165:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘cwait’
  165 |   intptr_t __cdecl cwait(int *_TermStat,intptr_t _ProcHandle,int _Action) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
      |                    ^~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:177:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘spawnl’
  177 |   intptr_t __cdecl spawnl(int,const char *_Filename,const char *_ArgList,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
      |                    ^~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:178:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘spawnle’
  178 |   intptr_t __cdecl spawnle(int,const char *_Filename,const char *_ArgList,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
      |                    ^~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:179:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘spawnlp’
  179 |   intptr_t __cdecl spawnlp(int,const char *_Filename,const char *_ArgList,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
      |                    ^~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:180:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘spawnlpe’
  180 |   intptr_t __cdecl spawnlpe(int,const char *_Filename,const char *_ArgList,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
      |                    ^~~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:196:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘spawnv’
  196 |   _CRTIMP intptr_t __cdecl spawnv(int,const char *_Filename,char *const _ArgList[]) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
      |                            ^~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:197:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘spawnve’
  197 |   _CRTIMP intptr_t __cdecl spawnve(int,const char *_Filename,char *const _ArgList[],char *const _Env[]) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
      |                            ^~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:198:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘spawnvp’
  198 |   _CRTIMP intptr_t __cdecl spawnvp(int,const char *_Filename,char *const _ArgList[]) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
      |                            ^~~~~~~
C:\msys64\mingw64\include/process.h:199:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘spawnvpe’
  199 |   _CRTIMP intptr_t __cdecl spawnvpe(int,const char *_Filename,char *const _ArgList[],char *const _Env[]) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
```

Could these errors potentially be related to the absence of the "zlib.h" file or another underlying issue? Could these errors potentially be related to the absence of the "zlib.h" file or another underlying issue? Help would be much appreciated.

I tried to install, and re-install zlib on my MSYS2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. -- It appears errors start `from main.c:1:` double check.

Comment: Apparently all these specific keyword definitions (`_CRTIMP`, `__cdecl`, ...) are missing, and the identifiers are seen as symbols. You might want to re-install everything correctly. It seems that your repair attempt failed.